# How to remove Empty Properties from a multi depth JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I've got this JS Object:

```
var test = {"code_operateur":[""],"cp_cult":["",""],"annee":["2011"],"ca_cult":[""]}
```

When I use this function:

```
for (i in test) {  
   if ( test[i] == "" || test[i] === null ) {  
       delete test[i];  
    }  
}
```

I get:

```
{"cp_cult":["",""],"annee":["2011"]}
```

Okay not bad, but I'd like to remove the empty "cp_cult" property (which is an array and not a string like the other).

Note: I don't want to manually delete the key!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function isEmpty(thingy) {
 for(var k in thingy){
  if(thingy[k]) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

for(i in test) {
 if ( test[i] == "" || test[i] === null || (typeof test[i] == "object" && isEmpty(test[i])) ) {
  delete test[i];
 }
}
```

However, depending on the complexity of the object, you'd need more advanced algorithms. For example, if the array can contain another array of empty strings (or even more levels) and it should be deleted, you'd need to check for that as well.

**EDIT:** Trying to make something to fit your needs, please have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/jVHNe/

Comment: The typeof operator will never return "array"

Comment: Other possibility for conditional without isEmpty function:

    ( test[i] == "" || test[i] === null || (test[i] && test[i].join && !test[i].join("")) )

Comment: Primvdb : still something to improve:
I can still get 
{"cp_cult":["25",""],"annee":["2011"]} 
which I'd like to avoid. 
It has to be: 
{"cp_cult":["25"],"annee":["2011"]}  Any Idea ?

Comment: If `cp_cult` is `["", ""]` it should be removed and if it is `["something", ""]`, it should become `["something"]`, is that correct?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: the `isEmpty()` function won't work exactly as expected if the `thingy` has a property with a value of `false` or `0`, of course

Comment: @oracle certified professional: The OP's constraints were `null` or `""` so that's what I basically copied. Of course one can tweak it like he wants.

Comment: @pimvdb that's fine, I was just remarking for completeness. it wasn't mentioned previously

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're asking 2 questions here.

1. How do I remove a property of an object; and
2. How can I tell if an object is actually an array.

You can delete a property of an object using the `delete` operator.

```
delete test.cp_cult;
```

In JavaScript arrays are objects, which means that `typeof([])` unhelpfully returns `object`.  Typically people work around this by using a function in a framework (`dojo.isArray` or something similar) or rolling their own method that determines if an object is an array.

There is no 100% guaranteed way to determine if an object is actually an array.  Most people just check to see if it has some of the methods/properties of an array `length`, `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`, etc.