# How should i delete "id" key from all level(model,array) of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json array which looks something like this:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Array1": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Model1": {
            "id": 3,
            "Model2": {
                "id": 4,
                "A": "a"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Model3": {
            "id": 3,
            "Model4": {
                "id": 4,
                "B": "b"
            }
        }
    }]
    "Model4":
    {
        "id": 5,
        "C" : "c"
    }
}
```

I would like to have a function which removes the elements "id" from all level. How can i do it ?

Comment: You need recursive function to traverse object and delete  its direct `id` properties and `id` properties from its ancestors. Take a look at these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344356/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-a-property-from-nested-javascript-object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123728/remove-redundant-properties-from-javascript-object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446426/how-do-you-recursively-remove-nested-objects-that-contain-an-empty-array

Comment: There is no such thing as a *JSON array*.

Comment: @KooiInc: I'm assuming you're making the point that there's only such thing as a JSON-_encoded_ array

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using JSON, it's quite simple. Once you get the string (because JSON is a string format), you will parse it using the `reviver` argument of [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method:

```
var filteredObject = JSON.parse(textData, function (k, v) {
    return k === 'id' ? undefined : v;
});
```